# No images in TListview header when using VCL Styles

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles, tlistview

When using a TListview in vsReport ViewStyle with any VCL Styles activated, the images in the header are not shown. Unsing the classic Windows style, the images appear. (The way to show the images I use is to assign a TImageList to the SmallImages property of the ListView and then select an image index in the Columns property for the respective column). How can I show images in the header of a TListView with VCL Styles enabled?

Answer (score 6):

I just added a new vcl style hook ([TListViewStyleHookFix](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.Fixes.pas)) for the TListView component in the [Vcl Styles Utils project](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/) to fix this issue.

You can use this Stylehook adding the *[Vcl.Styles.Fixes](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.Fixes.pas)* unit to you uses clause and then register the hook on this way.

```
 TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TListView, TListViewStyleHookFix);
```

[image]

You can found more details about this fix on this blog [entry](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/added-new-vcl-style-hook-to-the-vcl-styles-utils-to-fix-qc-108678-108875-xe2-and-xe3/).